# How to parse such JSON response in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm developing a Google Analytics connector for the Microsoft SQL Server.

The connector must be able to make multiple queries to different GA accounts (by view id), with different dates, metrics and dimensions.

Actually, bypassing the connection to the API and database, I make a request to GA API v4.

Config are written in a nested dictionary, then they are parsed, responses are converted into pandas df and so far are written in a list.

Everything was ok, until the API response was processed. The view id, start and end dates are specified in the config, but not in the API response. And without them, there is no sense in loading the data further to the database. With the date I can get it, indicating it as a dimension, but without view id it is very sad.

I have no idea how to get view id, get it out of the config or when I make a request to the API and whether it is real or not

the code:

```py
#config 

data_test = {

    'view_id_11111' : {'view_id': '11111', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:userType'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]},

    'view_id_2222' : {'view_id': '22222', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]},

    'view_id_3333' : {'view_id': '3333', 
                           'start_date': '2019-08-01', 
                           'end_date': '2019-09-01',
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}]}


}

#blank list for responses 
responses = []

#parsing of the nested dict data_test
for k, v in data_test.items():

    sample_request = {
        'viewId': v['view_id'],
        'dateRanges': {
            'startDate': v['start_date'],
            'endDate': v['end_date']
        },
        'metrics': v['metrics'],
        'dimensions': v['dimensions']
    }
    #делаю запрос к апи ГА
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': sample_request
        }).execute()
    #print_response_new(response) function for converting responses into dfs


    n_response=print_response_new(response)
    responses.append(n_response)

#print_response_new(response) function for converting responses into dfs
def print_response_new(response):

    list = []

    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])


        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            dict[header] = dimension


        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

        list.append(dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    return df
```

Example of the API response

```
{"reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:users",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "metrics": [
              {"values": ["54"]}
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [{"values": ["54"]}],
        "minimums": [{"values": ["54"]}],
        "maximums": [{"values": ["54"]}],
        "rowCount": 1,
      }
    }
]}
```

Comment: But don't you *know* the `view_id` when you're making the request? simply pass the view_id to `print_response_new`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's kinda dynamic. Or you mean like that: df['view_id'] = sample_request.get('viewId')?

Comment: @AnnaDmitrievav Do not add CLOSED, SOLVED or similar to the title of your publication as it is not necessary. You already published an answer and in 2 days you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the 'view_id' field directly from the request to the APIs

```py
df['view_id'] = sample_request.get('viewId')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, consider explaining why and how it works.